# Import 2GB .sql file with pgAdmin 4.15

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a 2GB .sql file with COPY format which was exported from phpPgAdmin.  I am not able to get it in any other format.

Presumably due to its size, when I try to use the open file option in the query tool, it spins for a while but then brings up a blank text area with the file name as the tab name.

Is there some method to import this file using pgAdmin 4.15?

Comment: if you have access to the server please include the error message/log, this could be file size limit in php settings or could be time out error due to large file size and it took much time to upload, error logs can help her.

Comment: It is amazon RDS, I have no idea how to grab logs from that but my understanding is that the query tool open file button loads the query into the window, it doesn't send it to the server.

Comment: if you have access to the dashboard, CLI or AWS API check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html

Comment: Nothing in the log file.

Comment: my guess is that the file is big and you have limitation either from PhpPgAdmin or timeout error, how about your try to use terminal to `psql <` to import the database dump file, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import it should give you errors if it fails.

Comment: The export from PhpPgAdmin is fine.  The problem is pgAdmin (NOT PhpPgAdmin) which I am trying to use to import.

Comment: Well, if pgAdmin can't deal with it, use `psql` simple as that

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in some `COPY` format, then loading it into the query window won't help; if it did ever finish loading, you'd just see a pile of raw data, not an executable script.

To import a file in a `COPY` format, navigate to the target table in the object browser on the left, right-click it, and choose "Import/Export...".

The settings in the import dialog correspond directly to the [options in the `COPY` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), so be sure to select the same format, delimiter, etc. as were used in the original export.